# IE7 Negative value cuts off half the element - bug?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I've relatively positioned one of the elements with negative 'top' and 'left' values, the negative 'left' value actually takes the element outside of the 'body' width, this seems fine in all browsers apart from IE7 where it just cuts it off.

[establi.sh](http://establi.sh)

I thought it might be that weird bug where if it's outside the parent container then you have to set a z-index but that didn't work, then I thought it might be the hasLayout bug but trying to fix that didn't work.

I'm not an expert on IE browsers so need some help. I'm thinking IE7 might be choking as the negative left value actually takes it outside the body?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

E7 doesn't support negative margins the way you want it to. Fortunately, you can easily just increase the width of your body tag, and then increase the left style of the rest of your absolute divs and accomplish the same result.